# Git deploy - one project into two folders

Tags: php, laravel, git, cpanel

I have a laravel project and I want to deploy it to the server with git push and split it into two separate folders, Laravel usually has app dir that goes into root and public folder that goes into public_html

How that can be achieved.

I have cpanel server, is that possibles I tried to search all over google.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only `cpanel` then you can connect only through ftp. If you don't have `ssh` access you can't deploy the project using `git`.

Comment: I do have ssh, my main problem is all the project in one repository on git, but on production server the project supoose to be splited into two folders, laravel main folder in root and public folder in public html , how git push can deploy and split from one repository into different folders?

Comment: When you push you will have the same folder structure, git is for versioning. I suggest you do what  you want with bash or something else.

Comment: I dont agree on the part git is for versioning only, I use git to deploy my projects to Heroku on daily basis, also you can deploy projects on cpanel as well , example link deploy to cpanel
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+Deployment